# How to match the value in the column with the name of the other column present in the dataframe and then calculate the corresponding percent change?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a similar dataset as mentioned below:

| ID | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | col3 | 10 | 9 | 5 | 4 |
| 2 | col5 | 6 | 7 | 4 | 8 |
| 3 | col3 | 12 | 4 | 2 | 11 |
| 4 | col4 | 9 | 5 | 8 | 10 |

In col1, the data has values of some column names of the same dataframe.
I need to match the values in col1 with the actual names of the column in the dataframe and then compute the percentage change in the values with col2.

The expected output table can be given as:

| ID | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | percent_change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | col3 | 10 | 9 | 5 | 4 | (10-9)/9*100 is 11.11% |
| 2 | col5 | 6 | 7 | 4 | 8 | (6-8)/8*100 is -25% |
| 3 | col3 | 12 | 4 | 2 | 11 | (12-4)/4*100 is 200% |
| 4 | col4 | 9 | 5 | 8 | 10 | (9-8)/8*100 is 12.5% |

So for ID:1, col1 has the value col3. So the code should find that col3 and calculate the percentage of the value under it with the col2.

Similarly, for ID:2, col1 has the value col5, so the code should find col5 and find the percentage change with the corresponding value in col2. That is, here col5 is 8 and col2 is 6. Then calculate the percentage change.

I tried some approaches but got the wrong output.

Please help me with the python pandas code for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get values by [lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup) and then count new column with arithmetic operations:

```
idx, cols = pd.factorize(df['col1'])

s = df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]

df['percent_change'] = df['col2'].sub(s).div(s).mul(100)

print (df)
   ID  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  percent_change
0   1  col3    10     9     5     4       11.111111
1   2  col5     6     7     4     8      -25.000000
2   3  col3    12     4     2    11      200.000000
3   4  col4     9     5     8    10       12.500000
```